# On signaling a condition variable, what happens to mutex ownership?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-programming

1. Thread *T1* locks mutex *M* and waits on condition *C* (releasing *M*).
2. Thread *T2* locks mutex *M* and signals condition *C*.

In literature it's stated that once *C* is signaled, *T1* wakes up and reacquires *M*.

I was left doubtful for what happens with *T2* since it had *M* acquired before signaling *C*.

What happens to *T2* regarding *M* which was acquired before signaling?

1. Does *T1* gets ready but blocked, executing only after *T2* releases *M*, for it to be reacquired?
2. Does *T1* gets ready and executes while *T2* gets blocked till *M* gets released, for it to be reacquired?
3. They just execute concurrently, *T1* with *M* acquired, *T2* with *M* released (or also acquired?)
4. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signalling the condition C wakes up the thread T1, then it has to reacquires the mutex M by locking it. In order to do so, T2 must release M first.

So the answer is, T1 wakes up on signal, waits to acquire M, T2 releases M, T1 acquires M, T1 and T2 execute concurrently.

Comment: now I see how obvious it's since *T1* wakes and locks when signaled, but locking doesn't mean acquire.